# Grab logged_in user info in PHP template and assign variables

Tags: templates, php, forum

can you help me writing this lines of code for grab in a EE template the information about a logged_in user, using php.

I'm using Vanilla Forum, and i want to use the JsConnect to pass the logged_in user information to the Vanilla Log in. Here's the guide:

[Implementing Vanilla jsConnect Single-Signon on your Site](http://vanillaforums.com/blog/help/implementing-jsconnect-single-signon-on/)

I found that libraries to include in system

[PHP jsConnect client library](https://github.com/vanillaforums/jsConnectPHP)

And the code to include in my page template is this:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/functions.jsconnect.php';

// 1. Get your client ID and secret here. These must match those in your jsConnect settings.
$clientID = "1234";
$secret = "1234";

// 2. Grab the current user from your session management system or database here.
$signedIn = true; // this is just a placeholder

// YOUR CODE HERE.

// 3. Fill in the user information in a way that Vanilla can understand.
$user = array();

if ($signedIn) {
   // CHANGE THESE FOUR LINES.
   $user['uniqueid'] = '123';
   $user['name'] = 'John PHP';
   $user['email'] = 'john.php@anonymous.com';
   $user['photourl'] = '';
}

// 4. Generate the jsConnect string.

// This should be true unless you are testing. 
// You can also use a hash name like md5, sha1 etc which must be the name as the connection settings in Vanilla.
$secure = true; 
WriteJsConnect($user, $_GET, $clientID, $secret, $secure);
```

How can i call the logged_in user info here

```
// 2. Grab the current user from your session management system or database here.
$signedIn = true; // this is just a placeholder

// YOUR CODE HERE.
```

with this

```
{if logged_in}
UniqueID={member_id}
Name={username}
Email={email}
PhotoUrl={photo_url}{photo_filename}
{/if}
```

And assign that the variables to pass to

```
// 3. Fill in the user information in a way that Vanilla can understand.
$user = array();

if ($signedIn) {
   // CHANGE THESE FOUR LINES.
   $user['uniqueid'] = '123';
   $user['name'] = 'John PHP';
   $user['email'] = 'john.php@anonymous.com';
   $user['photourl'] = '';
}
```

To generate a json file that vanilla JsConnect can read?

I think also

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/functions.jsconnect.php';
```

return error in ExpressionEngine

Please somebody can tell me how can solve this.

Thank you in advance
Alessio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in a template you can just use:
{member_id}
{username}
{email}

If you want to use all php you can use the Session class:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html

```
$user['uniqueid'] = $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id');
$user['name'] = $this->EE->session->userdata('username');
$user['email'] = $this->EE->session->userdata('email');
```

You'd probably be better off writing an extension that takes care of this at login than in a template.

Comment: Can i grab $user['photourl'] = ''; with session?

Comment: Here is a list of the data contained in $this->EE->session->userdata()
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#user-data-information
You have the member_id, you can always run a query against exp_members based on that to pull the additional data you need.